# How to get query params in an Angular app without the need of state or route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need query params in the url for my Single-Page Angular app. I simply need to access this data.

Currently, I am using `$location.absUrl()` to achieve this and running a simple JS `split('?')` on it which gives me the query.

Is there any better way to achieve this without getting into the complexities of router or state.

P.S. Picked up Angular today. Go easy!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$location.search()` method. It returns an object of all url parameters and their values.

```
// given url http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
var searchObject = $location.search();
// => {foo: 'bar', baz: 'xoxo'}
```

This example is taken from the official Angular documentation about $location service. 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$location` for dealing with query params.

Eg: Your URL be like

> `http://blah.com?q1=aa&q2=bb`

then

> $location.search()

will return you a neat object `

> {   q1 : "aa",   q2 : "bb" }`

**Be sure you inject $location in your controller!!**

Read more in the [official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)